# Unknown Provider when adding service to controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-services

I created a Modal service and when I injected the service into the controller, I am receiving an error that says "$Injector: unpr Unknown Provider". Here is my code below. Let me know if I am missing something.

**This is the service I have so far.**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.services', [])

.factory('modalService', ['$scope', function($scope) {
return {
    openMenuModal: function(templateLink, windowAnimation) {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: templateLink,
            backdrop: 'static',
            windowClass: windowAnimation,
            controller: function($scope, $modalInstance) {
                $scope.close = function() {
                    $modalInstance.close();
                };
            },
            size: 'md',
            scope: $scope,
            keyboard: true
        });

    }
};

}]);
```

**Here is the controller I have set up.**

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate'])
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $http, $modal, modalService) {
    $scope.opentheBook = modalService.openMenuModal('partials/Books.html', 'animated zoomIn');
});
```

**Here is the template for the data in the modal - Books.html**

```
<div ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
<div class="modalBox animated fadeIn">
<button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" type="button" ng-click="" tooltip="Close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
<h1>title</h1>
<p>description</p>
<div class="next">
<button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" type="button" tooltip="Close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Here is the main home page where I am calling the openBook() to open the modal with the info from the json**

```
    <div class="Books">
                  <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="book in thing.Books" class="list-unstyled"><a ng-click="opentheBook" href="#"><h6>{{book.name}}</h6></a></li>
                   </ul>
            </div>
```

**json for Books example --inside another array called things**

```
"Books": [
            {
                "name": "Name of Book 1",
                "description": "Description about book..."
            },
            {
                "name": "Name of Book 2",
                "description": "Description about book..."
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Please provide [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)

Comment: Factories dont get a `$scope` injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error results from the `$injector` being unable to resolve a required dependency. To fix this, **make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly.** For example, the following code will fail with the same error you received -`$injector:unpr`, if myService is not defined:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MyController', ['myService', function (myService) {
  // Do something with myService
}]);
```

Making sure each dependency is defined will fix the problem, as noted below.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.service('myService', function () { /* ... */ })
.controller('MyController', ['myService', function (myService) {
  // Do something with myService
}]);
```

**So to answer your question, in your case you appear to be missing dependency**

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate'])
.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $http, $modal, modalService) {
    $scope.opentheBook = modalService.openMenuModal('partials/Books.html', 'animated zoomIn');
});
```

To Inject `modalService` like so:

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', ['modalService', function($scope, $http, $modal, modalService) {

    }]);
```

You also need to change up your `factory` module to `angular.module('myApp.services', ['ui.bootstrap'])` and use `$uibModal` since `$modal` is deprecated.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])

.factory('modalService', ['$uibModal', function($uibModal) {

  return {
    openMenuModal: function(templateLink, windowAnimation) {

        var modalObj = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl: templateLink,
            backdrop: 'static',
            windowClass: windowAnimation,
            controller: function($scope,$modalInstance){
              $scope.ok = function(id){
                //Process OK Button Click
                 $modalInstance.close(); 
              },
               $scope.cancel = function(){
                $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
              }
            },
            size: 'md',
            keyboard: true,
            resolve: {
              someData: function () {
                return 'Return some Data';
              }
          }
        });
    }
};
}])

.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope','modalService', function($scope, modalService, someData) {
   $scope.dataFromService = someData;
   $scope.opentheBook = function(){
      modalService.openMenuModal('myModalContent.html', 'animated zoomIn');
    };
}]);
```

**UPDATE 1**

As mentioned in the comments, do not attempt to inject `$scope` to your factory.  Here is a Plunker I created which lets you open a modal by calling the factory.

http://plnkr.co/edit/G68NVYZlTqrIS0N2TKL4

Comment: I did this exactly and still it throws an error. I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: @LadyT Try my updated answer, make the changes to factory to also inject - `$modalInstance`.

Comment: Thanks. I copied the new code exactly and checked my controller to make sure I wasn't missing anything, but it still is throwing errors.

Comment: @LadyT Can you update your question with the errors you are receiving, if different from the one you got before?

Comment: The error I am receiving says " Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider

Unknown provider: $modalInstanceProvider <- $modalInstance <- HomeCtrl". This is the new error, but still the same.

Comment: @LadyT ok, change the module dependency injection to inject in `myapp.Services`.  So do, `angular.module('myApp.services', ['ui.bootstrap'])` where  you `factory` is. Check my update.

Comment: Removed my answer as this one's more descriptive and leads to the solution

Comment: @Dayan So I added the 'ui.bootstrap' into the service module and I got an error that says "$injector: unpr. Unknown Provider". I also checked my view and it references the right controller and everything.

Comment: @LadyT Have you downloaded and added path to ui-bootstrap.js in your index.html?

Comment: @l0lander Yes. It was working before I started creating the service.

Comment: @LadyT Hmm. Do me a favor, include the html if you can so we can see bigger picture of whats going on.

Comment: @Dayan  So I added the HTML snippets in my main question so you can see them.

Comment: @LadyT You didn't add the most important part - script references

Comment: @l0lander okay, will add the scripts in the main.

Comment: @Dayan Thanks so much! It worked. The reason why I was having all of these issues was because the version of Ui.Boostrap was too old. So I updated to your link and it worked perfectly!! Thank you so much for helping me. I really appreciate it!!

Comment: @LadyT Anytime! :) GL