# Angular uibModal, Resolve, Unknown Provider

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to expose a "generic" modal - using Angular's [$uibModal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) - through a service. Here is the definition of that service:

```
angular.module('app').service('CustomModalService', ['$uibModal', function ($uibModal) {

    var openCustomModal = function (size, title, message) {
        var actionToPerformOnConfirm = action;

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            templateUrl : 'templates/CustomModal.html',
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                title: title,
                message: message
            }
        });
    };

    return {
        openCustomModal: openCustomModal
    };
}]);
```

Nothing too complicated, above. However, it is not working. If I remove the `resolve` property from the object, the service works; however, if I include the `resolve` property, I get the [Unknown Provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr) error originating from that property.

The documentation for the `resolve` property reads:

> (Type: Object) - Members that will be resolved and passed to the
>   controller as locals; it is equivalent of the resolve property in the
>   router.

The objective is to be able to provide a template for the modal that utilizes these properties in its DOM, e.g. :

```
<div ng-controller="CustomModalController">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        {{message}}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="ad-button ad-blue" type="button" ng-click="confirmAction()"></button>
        <button class="ad-button ad-blue" type="button" ng-click="cancelAction()"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing that is causing this error to be thrown?

Comment: 1) Do you have  ui-bootstrap installed and injected into your index.html? 2) Make sure to inject ui.bootstrap as well into your service. 3) Make sure you have latest ui.bootstrap installed.

Comment: I have ui-bootstrap installed and injected, yes.

Comment: Ok.. because in the service you have shown it is not injected. This might help as well - https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4603

Comment: @StephanKristyn does it need to be injected into the service, itself, for it to work? It is working, just to restate again, without the `resolve` property.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need a controller when you use resolve.

Comment: @MatthewGreen that's another issue that I am having. My controller is throwing the same error when I provide the controller property with a literal, e.g. `controller: 'MyController'`

Comment: Are you using a task runner of any kind? I had some strange issues when my task runner was accidently putting two different versions of angular-bootstrap in my app. Otherwise, I think you will need to build an example that gives shows this error because nothing seems to be jumping out as an issue.

Comment: Btw StackOverflow is full of solutions for this, I suggest using the search function, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130642/unknown-provider-when-adding-service-to-controller

Comment: Those solutions are very informative and I worked through many of them. I even found this one (more closely related): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645824/angular-bootstrap-uibmodal-not-resolve-attributs

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You need to define the controller in your modal config
2. Your resolve object needs to be a map of `string`: `function`, where `string` is the name of the dependency that will be injected into your modal's controller, and `function` is a factory function that will be used to provide that dependency when the controller is instantiated.

Working example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sscovil/fp2zewme/)

### JavaScript

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .controller('MyModalController', MyModalController)
  .directive('modalTrigger', modalTriggerDirective)
  .factory('$myModal', myModalFactory)
;

function MyModalController($uibModalInstance, items) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.content = items;
  vm.confirm = $uibModalInstance.close;
  vm.cancel = $uibModalInstance.dismiss;
};

function modalTriggerDirective($myModal) {
  function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
    function onClick() {
      var size = scope.$eval(iAttrs.size) || 'lg'; // default to large size
      var title = scope.$eval(iAttrs.title) || 'Default Title';
      var message = scope.$eval(iAttrs.message) || 'Default Message';
      $myModal.open(size, title, message);
    }
    iElement.on('click', onClick);
    scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      iElement.off('click', onClick);
    });
  }

  return {
    link: postLink
  };
}

function myModalFactory($uibModal) {
  var open = function (size, title, message) {
    return $uibModal.open({
      controller: 'MyModalController',
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      templateUrl : 'templates/CustomModal.html',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function() {
          return {
            title: title,
            message: message
          };
        }
      }
    });
  };

  return {
    open: open
  };
}
```

### HTML

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/CustomModal.html">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">{{vm.content.title}}</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    {{vm.content.message}}
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="ad-button ad-blue" type="button" ng-click="vm.confirm()">
      confirm
    </button>
    <button class="ad-button ad-blue" type="button" ng-click="vm.cancel()">
      cancel
    </button>
  </div>
</script>

<button modal-trigger size="'sm'" title="'Hello World!'" message="'This is a test'">
  Click Me
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! When I have access to a computer, tomorrow, I'll give it a shot

Comment: Thanks guys. Found a pretty sick article, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350463/angular-uibmodal-resolve-unknown-provider

What is the convention of naming the controller "vm"

Comment: The vm stands for ViewModel. See this article for more about that: http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/

Comment: Thanks @Shaun.  In the fiddle, the modal doesn't animate unless you click twice. Any idea why?

Comment: No idea, it's been a while since I've touched ui-bootstrap. Might want to test it on a few different browsers, try switching to the latest version, etc. if it persists, post a new question on SO. I'm out of pocket at the moment so I can't troubleshoot it.

Comment: Many thanks @ShaunScovil ! Pretty simple copy-pastable example to get a minimal modal configuration running. Don't know why but the examples at https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ seem to overcomplicate things instead of focusing at minimal configurations.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that each resolve property must be injected into the controller.