# Pass variable from modal to modal

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I´m trying to get variables from modal to an other modal, this is mi modal:

```
   <div id="contentModal" class="modal fade" >
        <div class="modal-content animate" tabindex="-1">
            <div class="modal-container-">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h1>Issue:  {{selected_issue.Issue}}</h1>
              </div>
                <div class="modal-body row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <h5 style="text-align: center;">Descripción</h5>                   
                        <p1>{{selected_issue.Descripcion}}</p1>
                      </div> 
                      <div class="col-md-5">
                        <h5 style="text-align: center;">Solución</h5>
                       <p1>{{selected_issue.Solucion}}</p1>
                      </div>


                    <div id="modalSpec"class="col-md-2">
                        <h6>OpCo:</h6>
                        <p1>{{selected_issue.opCo}}</p1>
                        <h6>Tecnologia:</h6>
                        <p1>{{selected_issue.Tecnology}}</p1>
                        <h6>Version:</h6>
                        <p1>{{selected_issue.Version}}</p1>
                        <h6>Estado:</h6>
                        <p1>{{selected_issue.Status}}</p1>
                        <h6>Autor:</h6>
                        <p1>{{selected_issue.Autor}}</p1>
                        <p1>{{id}}</p1>
                        <div>
                          <h6>Editar:</h6>
                          <select name='type' id='type'>
                          <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccionar</option>
                          <option value='OpCo' >Descripción</option>
                          <option value='Solucion' >Solución</option>
                          <option value='Estado' >Estado</option>
                          </select>
                          <div><button id"modalClose" type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button></div>  
                        </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

     </div>
              <script>
  $("#type").on("change", function () {        
      $modal = $('#secondModal');
      if($(this).val() === 'OpCo'){
        $modal.modal('show');
        $('#type').val('');
    }
 });
  </script>
  </div>
```

As the code shows, the script that triggers the second modal is inside the first modal.Whenever you select something from the dropdown menu, modal pops-up, but i do not know how to pass variables like for example {{selected_issue.Descripcion}}, also i would like to know how to pass the $index value from the array.

Thanks a lot to everyone.

Comment: I would use $uibModal service if you are using angularjs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35350463/angular-uibmodal-resolve-unknown-provider

Comment: try avoid using jquery on angular apps. better use like @Praveen says ui-bootstrap has modal service.

Comment: Pretty difficult to understand how to use this uibModal service...could you explain a little bit further applying to my case? @Praveen

Answer (score 0):

$uibModal is a service to create modal windows. Creating modals is straightforward: create a template and controller, and reference them when using $uibModal. The $uibModal service has only one method: open(options).

Refer to 'open multiple modals at once' button in the [`Plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

For more info refer [`this link`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal)

Now, in your case try pasting your markup code and use resolve object which is in open() or openComponentModal().