# Call Child Controller from another Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application with add and edit modal,when click edit or add ;it's open a modal.
my Problem is :I want to have a function that's open a modal Just by call it and this function I want to define it in the root scope,when I do that I have an error in the resolve function.

```
DefaultModule.controller("navCtrl", function ($scope, $rootScope, $uibModal) {       
    $rootScope.OpenModal = function (templateModalUrl, controllerModal, resolveFun) {
        $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: templateModalUrl,
            controller: controllerModal,
            resolve: {
                resolveFun
            }
        }).result.catch(function (res) {
            if (!(res === 'cancel' || res === 'escape key press')) {
                //throw res;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

calling it:

```
$scope.editBusiness = function (business) {
    var ObjResolve = function () {
        return business;
    }
    $rootScope.OpenModal("BusinessTypesModal.html", "ModalInstanceCtrl", ObjResolve);
};
```

and the error that's I get:

> Error: $injector:unpr
>       Unknown Provider
>       Unknown provider: ObjResolveProvider <- ObjResolve <- ModalInstanceCtrl

P.S. the template of the modal is defined in another controller -not navCtrl Controller-

Comment: Are you sure that the file that contains `ModalInstanceCtrl` is actually loaded, e.g. in your index.html or however you include your files? The error hints on `ModalInstanceCtrl` never being declared which usually means that the file is not included during page load. As a side note, I suggest putting the function `OpenModal` into a service and injecting the service whenever it's needed. That`s a cleaner option than putting it in `$rootScope`.

Comment: @FlorianLim yes thank you that's a pretty Answer

Comment: but I still have the same error

Comment: After checking the error message again, I see that the problem is not the `ModalInstanceCtrl` but the `ObjResolve` parameter. That has to meet certain criteria, as can be seen in another SO question: [Angular uibModal, Resolve, Unknown Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35352546/634872). The relevant part is _Your resolve object needs to be a map of string: function_.